# Manipulating a character vector by considering a grouping Q-matrix in r (2)

Tags: r, character

I am trying to write code based on a `Group` variable, `item.map` that has item information that includes an q-matrix showing which item is associated with which group.

```
    Group <- c(1,2,3,4)
item.map <- data.frame(
  item.id = c(21,41,61,72),
  group.1 = c(1,1,1,0),
  group.2 = c(0,1,0,1),
  group.3 = c(1,1,1,0),
  group.4 = c(0,0,0,1))

> item.map
  item.id group.1 group.2 group.3 group.4
1      21       1       0       1       0
2      41       1       1       1       0
3      61       1       0       1       0
4      72       0       1       0       1
```

In this `item.map` group.1 had 3 items while group.2 has two items, `group.3` has three and `group.4` has 1 item.. Using this item.map I wanted to assign those items within the chunk of code below but I was not able to plug the `item.map` information.

```
   OUTPUT <- as.data.frame(c())
for(i in 1:length(item.map$item.id)) {
 
  for(k in 0:(length(Group))) { # here with the length(State) I gained the sequqnece of 0,1,2,3
    output <- paste0("Equal = ",paste0(paste("(", "G1, ",item.map$item.id[i], ","," Slope[",k,"])",collapse=", ", sep=""),", ",
                                        paste( "(", "G2, ",item.map$item.id[i], ","," Slope[",k,"])",collapse=", ", sep=""),
                                        ";"))
    OUTPUT <- c(OUTPUT, output)
    
  }
}


[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G2, 21, Slope[0]), (G3, 21, Slope[0]), (G4, 21, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]), (G2, 21, Slope[1]), (G3, 21, Slope[1]), (G4, 21, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[2]), (G2, 21, Slope[2]), (G3, 21, Slope[2]), (G4, 21, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[3]), (G2, 21, Slope[3]), (G3, 21, Slope[3]), (G4, 21, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[4]), (G2, 21, Slope[4]), (G3, 21, Slope[4]), (G4, 21, Slope[4]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]), (G3, 41, Slope[0]), (G4, 41, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[1]), (G2, 41, Slope[1]), (G3, 41, Slope[1]), (G4, 41, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[2]), (G2, 41, Slope[2]), (G3, 41, Slope[2]), (G4, 41, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[3]), (G2, 41, Slope[3]), (G3, 41, Slope[3]), (G4, 41, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[4]), (G2, 41, Slope[4]), (G3, 41, Slope[4]), (G4, 41, Slope[4]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[0]), (G2, 61, Slope[0]), (G3, 61, Slope[0]), (G4, 61, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[1]), (G2, 61, Slope[1]), (G3, 61, Slope[1]), (G4, 61, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[2]), (G2, 61, Slope[2]), (G3, 61, Slope[2]), (G4, 61, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[3]), (G2, 61, Slope[3]), (G3, 61, Slope[3]), (G4, 61, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[4]), (G2, 61, Slope[4]), (G3, 61, Slope[4]), (G4, 61, Slope[4]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 72, Slope[0]), (G2, 72, Slope[0]), (G3, 72, Slope[0]), (G4, 72, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 72, Slope[1]), (G2, 72, Slope[1]), (G3, 72, Slope[1]), (G4, 72, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 72, Slope[2]), (G2, 72, Slope[2]), (G3, 72, Slope[2]), (G4, 72, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 72, Slope[3]), (G2, 72, Slope[3]), (G3, 72, Slope[3]), (G4, 72, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 72, Slope[4]), (G2, 72, Slope[4]), (G3, 72, Slope[4]), (G4, 72, Slope[4]);"
```

So, in the desired output, `G1` should not have item `72` and G2 should not have items `21` and `61` information in the grouping chunk.
Also, I was not able to sequence "G1" and "G2" in my code. Is there a way to combine these two lines into one considering `G1`, `G2`, `G3` and `G4`?

```
output <- paste0("Equal = ",paste0(paste("(", "G1, ",item.map$item.id[i], ","," Slope[",k,"])",collapse=", ", sep=""),", ",
                                       paste("(", "G2, ",item.map$item.id[i], ","," Slope[",k,"])",collapse=", ", sep=""),", ",
                                       paste("(", "G3, ",item.map$item.id[i], ","," Slope[",k,"])",collapse=", ", sep=""),", ",
                                       paste( "(", "G4, ",item.map$item.id[i], ","," Slope[",k,"])",collapse=", ", sep=""),
                                       
                                       ";"))
```

The desired output is:

```
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G3, 21, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]), (G3, 21, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[2]), (G3, 21, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[3]), (G3, 21, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[4]), (G3, 21, Slope[4]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]), (G3, 41, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[1]), (G2, 41, Slope[1]), (G3, 41, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[2]), (G2, 41, Slope[2]), (G3, 41, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[3]), (G2, 41, Slope[3]), (G3, 41, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[4]), (G2, 41, Slope[4]), (G3, 41, Slope[4]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[0]), (G3, 61, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[1]), (G3, 61, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[2]), (G3, 61, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[3]), (G3, 61, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[4]), (G3, 61, Slope[4]);"
[1] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[0]), (G4, 72, Slope[0]);"
[1] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[1]), (G4, 72, Slope[1]);"
[1] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[2]), (G4, 72, Slope[2]);"
[1] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[3]), (G4, 72, Slope[3]);"
[1] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[4]), (G4, 72, Slope[4]);"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please choose between this question and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000557/manipulating-a-character-vector-by-considering-a-grouping-q-matrix-in-r-3 ... either delete that one or delete this one. Please do not keep both open.

Comment: these questions are slightly different actually.

Comment: Here, I think you need one more nested loop for 'group1', ;group2', because k is looping from 0:group and in R, indexing starts from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` where we loop over the 'group' column names, `select` those from 'item.map in a `list`, `rename` it to 'G1', 'G2', then do `crossing` to expand the dataset, `filter` based on the logical group column, create the expression with `glue_data` (from `grlue`) and `flatten` the `list` to a `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
out <- map(c('group.1', 'group.2'), 
      ~ item.map %>% 
          select(item.id, .x) %>% 
          rename_at(.x, ~ str_c('G', str_remove(., "\\D+"))) %>% 
          crossing(k = 0:2) %>%
          filter(across(starts_with('G'), as.logical)) %>% 
          glue::glue_data("Equal = ({names(.)[2]}, {item.id}, Slope[{k}]);")%>%
          as.character) %>%
    flatten_chr
```

-output

```
out
#[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]);" "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]);" "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[2]);" "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]);"
#[5] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[1]);" "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[2]);" "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[0]);" "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[1]);"
#[9] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[2]);" "Equal = (G2, 41, Slope[0]);" "Equal = (G2, 41, Slope[1]);" "Equal = (G2, 41, Slope[2]);"
#[13] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[0]);" "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[1]);" "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[2]);"
```

If we want to group those that are 1 in both groups,

```
i1 <- ave(seq_along(out), sub("G\\d+", "", out), FUN = length)

 out[i1 > 1] <- ave(out[i1 > 1], sub("Equal = \\(G\\d+", "", out[i1 > 1]), 
      FUN = function(x) {
          x[1] <- sub(";", "", x[1])
          paste(x[1], sub("Equal = ", "", x[2]), sep =", ")
  })
out1 <- unique(out)
out1

#[1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]);"                     "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]);"                    
#[3] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[2]);"                     "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]);"
#[5] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[1]), (G2, 41, Slope[1]);" "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[2]), (G2, 41, Slope[2]);"
#[7] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[0]);"                     "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[1]);"                    
#[9] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[2]);"                     "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[0]);"                    
#[11] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[1]);"                     "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[2]);"
```

#### Update

With the updated dataset

```
out <- map(c('group.1', 'group.2', 'group.3', 'group.4'), 
       ~ item.map %>% 
            select(item.id, .x) %>% 
            rename_at(.x, ~ str_c('G', str_remove(., "\\D+"))) %>% 
            crossing(k = 0:4) %>%
            filter(across(starts_with('G'), as.logical)) %>% 
            glue::glue_data("Equal = ({names(.)[2]}, {item.id}, Slope[{k}]);")%>%
            as.character) %>%
      flatten_chr
 
out[i1 > 1] <- ave(out[i1 > 1], sub("Equal = \\(G\\d+", "", out[i1 > 1]),
     FUN = function(x) {
      x[-length(x)] <- sub(";", "", x[-length(x)])
      paste(x[1], paste(sub("Equal = ", "", x[-1]), collapse = ", "), sep=", ") 
   })
   
unique(out)
 [1] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[0]), (G3, 21, Slope[0]);"                    
 [2] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[1]), (G3, 21, Slope[1]);"                    
 [3] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[2]), (G3, 21, Slope[2]);"                    
 [4] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[3]), (G3, 21, Slope[3]);"                    
 [5] "Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[4]), (G3, 21, Slope[4]);"                    
 [6] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]), (G3, 41, Slope[0]);"
 [7] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[1]), (G2, 41, Slope[1]), (G3, 41, Slope[1]);"
 [8] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[2]), (G2, 41, Slope[2]), (G3, 41, Slope[2]);"
 [9] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[3]), (G2, 41, Slope[3]), (G3, 41, Slope[3]);"
[10] "Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[4]), (G2, 41, Slope[4]), (G3, 41, Slope[4]);"
[11] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[0]), (G3, 61, Slope[0]);"                    
[12] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[1]), (G3, 61, Slope[1]);"                    
[13] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[2]), (G3, 61, Slope[2]);"                    
[14] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[3]), (G3, 61, Slope[3]);"                    
[15] "Equal = (G1, 61, Slope[4]), (G3, 61, Slope[4]);"                    
[16] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[0]), (G4, 72, Slope[0]);"                    
[17] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[1]), (G4, 72, Slope[1]);"                    
[18] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[2]), (G4, 72, Slope[2]);"                    
[19] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[3]), (G4, 72, Slope[3]);"                    
[20] "Equal = (G2, 72, Slope[4]), (G4, 72, Slope[4]);"
```

---

Or with the nested `for` loop

```
OUTPUT <- c()
# // loop over the sequence of rows
for(i in seq_len(nrow(item.map))) {
    # // nested loop to expand on a sequence
    for(k in  0:2) {  
        # // do a second nest based on the 'Group'  
         for(j in seq_along(Group)) {
              # // create a logical expression based on the 'group' column
              i1 <- as.logical(item.map[[paste0("group.", j)]][i])
              # // if it is TRUE, then only do the below
              if(i1) {
                  # // create the expression with paste
                  output <- paste0("Equal = ", paste("(", "G", j, 
                     ", ", item.map$item.id[i], ", Slope[", k, "])", 
                         collapse=", ", sep=""))
                 
              # // concatenate the NULL vector with the temporary output
              OUTPUT <- c(OUTPUT, output)
              }
         
         }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @akrun. for some reason, my R was not able to run the `map_c` function. Should I use any other library for it?

Comment: @amisos55 sorry, it is a typo.  Updated

Comment: @amisos55 I also added a `for` loop option.  Please check

Comment: Thanks for the two answers. You saved my day today :)

Comment: Hi @akrun, a quick question. I just realized that the output you produced and the one I desired have slight differences. For example:  the desired statement for `41` is  `"Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]);"` but in your output they are separate like this `"Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]);"` and `"Equal = (G2, 41, Slope[0]);"`. I would like to have them grouped under each `item.id` within one `Equal=` statement. Could you recommend a quick fix? sorry, I should have been realized this earlier. Also, `for` loop option does not insert `;` between statements.

Comment: @amisos55 So you don't want it separate?  I was looking at some of the expected like `"Equal = (G1, 21, Slope[2]);"`

Comment: @amisos55 is that only because both are 1s?

Comment: I need the ';` at the end of each but your `for` loop did not insert ';` but your first option did. my desired output is the one I am looking.

Comment: is this limited to two groups (`G1` and `G2`)? When I have four groups, should I change anything in the code?   especiall in this part? `FUN = function(x) {
                     x[1] <- sub(";", "", x[1])
                     paste(x[1], sub("Equal = ", "", x[2]), sep =", ")
                   })`

Comment: @amisos55 if you have more groups, then the second element would be `x[-1]` and it should be `paste(x[1], paste(sub("Equal = ", "", x[-1]), collapse = ", "), sep=", ")`

Comment: when I changed it to `x[-1]` it groups them in pairs. I have four groups in total so it is like `"Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]);"`  `"Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G3, 41, Slope[0]);"`  `"Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G4, 41, Slope[0]);"`. I would want them like  `"Equal = (G1, 41, Slope[0]), (G2, 41, Slope[0]), (G3, 41, Slope[0]), (G4, 41, Slope[0])"`

Comment: Do you have groups as in 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4'

Comment: @amisos55 can you please update with a new example, so that I can test it. thanks

Comment: This worked like a champ! Thank you for your time on it! :)

Comment: I ran this code but `across()` function gives an error `Error in across(starts_with("G"), as.logical) : 
  could not find function "across"`. Is it still in the `dplyr` library? Do you have any insights? thanks!

Comment: @amisos55 Can you check your `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  If you have a version >= 1.0.0, it should work

Comment: > packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.4’

Comment: @amisos55 that is the reason.  You may use `filter_at` for older versions

Comment: `filter(across(starts_with('G'), as.logical)) %>%` , this part needs to be modified as `filter_at(across(starts_with('G'), as.logical)) %>% ` , is this correct?

Comment: @amisos55 no, `across` is not available for that version.  You need `filter_at(vars(starts_with("G")), as.logical)`

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, this worked great! good day!