# Manipulating a character vector by considering a grouping Q-matrix in r (3)

Tags: r, character

I am trying to write code based on a `Group` variable, `item.map` that has item information that includes an q-matrix showing which item is associated with which group.

```
Group <- c(1,2)
item.map <- data.frame(
  item.id = c(21,41,61,72),
  group.1 = c(1,1,1,0),
  group.2 = c(0,1,0,1))

> item.map
  item.id group.1 group.2
1      21       1       0
2      41       1       1
3      61       1       0
4      72       0       1
```

In this `item.map` group.1 had 3 items while group.2 has two items. Using this item.map I wanted to assign those items within the chunk of code below but I was not able to plug the `item.map` information.

```
library(stringr)

# define df for all ids and group combinations
group_g <- paste("G", 1:length(Group), sep ="")
df <- data.frame(item.id = item.map$item.id, Group = rep(group_g, each = length(item.map$item.id)))

# empty vector
vec <- NULL


for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  res <- which(str_extract(df[i, "item.id"], "[0-9]{2,}") == item.map$item.id) # this part is for the item.id that has letters in it-not relevant in this example
  
  text <- paste("(", df[i, "Group"], ", ", df[i, "item.id"], ", fixed[", c(0:length(factor)) ,"]) = ", ifelse(res == 0:length(factor) | 0 == 0:length(factor), "1.0", "0.0"),";", sep = "")
  
  vec <- c(vec, text)
}

vec

 [1] "(G1, 21, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 21, fixed[1]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 41, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 41, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 61, fixed[0]) = 1.0;"
 [6] "(G1, 61, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 72, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 72, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G2, 21, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G2, 21, fixed[1]) = 1.0;"
[11] "(G2, 41, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G2, 41, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G2, 61, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G2, 61, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G2, 72, fixed[0]) = 1.0;"
[16] "(G2, 72, fixed[1]) = 0.0;"
```

So, in the desired output, `G1` should not have item `72` and G2 should not have items `21` and `61`

The desired output is:

```
 [1] "(G1, 21, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 21, fixed[1]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 41, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G1, 41, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 61, fixed[0]) = 1.0;"
 [6] "(G1, 61, fixed[1]) = 0.0;"
[11] "(G2, 41, fixed[0]) = 1.0;" "(G2, 41, fixed[1]) = 0.0;" "(G2, 72, fixed[0]) = 1.0;"
[16] "(G2, 72, fixed[1]) = 0.0;"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `str_extract` is vectorized.  Not sure why  you are looping over rows

Comment: some item.ids have letters in it in the full dataset. for example, I have 57_a and 57_b so I need to group them by 57. That part is a residual from the full code. This example does not have anything with that part of grouping.

Comment: the `==` part would not work because the lengths are not the same and it is not elementwise comparison.  You may need `%in%`

Comment: In the loop, you mentioned `0:length(factor)` I didn't see the `factor` object defined

Comment: Not getting the logic with `"(G1, 41, fixed[1]) = 0.0;"` i.e. 0.0.  Based on the values in the example, should that be `1.0`

Comment: I think I need to consider the structure again. Let me write this out again, do you mind take a look at the other post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000546/manipulating-a-character-vector-by-considering-a-grouping-q-matrix-in-r-2  this is less complex

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please update with more info regarding how you assigning 1.0, 0.0.  Also, the `factor` is not defined

Comment: @akrun I put the question in a better way now. sorry for the confusion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035136/manipulating-a-character-vector-by-considering-a-grouping-sequnce-in-r-4

Comment: thanks, will look into it

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have something similar question in the link below, Do you have time to take a look at that one? I have a similar post, since you helped on this before, could you please take a look at this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295192/write-out-a-statement-using-element-orders-from-matrices-for-matching-items-in-r

Comment: hi, i looked at the question only because you requested.